# Setting SonarQube's web context path via command line parameter

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Is it possible to set SonarQube's web context path using a command line parameter?

Usually you would set property `sonar.web.context=/sonarqube` (or similar) in `sonar.properties` file. But I'm using Docker and would like to avoid editing `sonar.properties`.

With Docker Compose I got the following which is working like a charm for other command line parameters:

```
services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:5.4
    [...]
    entrypoint:
      - ./bin/run.sh
      - -Dsonar.log.level=INFO
      - -Dsonar.web.context=/sonarqube
```

But it seems to ignore `-Dsonar.web.context=/sonarqube` :( Is there a way to pass SonarQube a different context path?

Additional info: This is corresponding [run.sh file](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/442f950dae232fca8e1e919e017270971cee46f6/5.4/run.sh).

Comment: With SonarQube 5.4 this is bound to fail: `sonar.web.context` was dropped in SonarQube 5.4 ([SONAR-7122](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7122)) and re-introduced in 5.5 ([SONAR-7494](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7494)). You should try with another SonarQube version first.

Comment: @n_stan your comment deserves to be an answer.

Comment: Yep. That's obviously the right answer. But if `sonar.web.context` parameter is dropped - what is official alternative for using SonarQube behind a reverse proxy? Is there some other parameter?

Comment: Fair enough for the answer, just thought it didn't address the actual Docker-related question. @Alex: for web context alternatives/discussion, see the [Upgrade Notes](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+5.4+Upgrade+Notes) and (long) [Jira thread](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7122).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With SonarQube 5.4 this is bound to fail: `sonar.web.context` was dropped in SonarQube 5.4 ([SONAR-7122](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7122), [suggested alternative](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+5.4+Upgrade+Notes) being to use a sub-domain) and re-introduced in 5.5 ([SONAR-7494](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7494)) following community feedback.

Comment: A subdomain is no alternative for me I fear :/ Solution is downgrading to 5.3 and skipping 5.4. Hope they keep context path option.

Answer (score 1):

They added the context back in 5.5 RC1

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7494